# What are IBinarySerialize Interface methods used for?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

When you create a custom aggregate function you need to specified the [enumeration format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Format Enumeration is used by SqlUserDefinedTypeAttribute and
>   SqlUserDefinedAggregateAttribute to indicate the serialization format
>   of a user-defined type (UDT) or aggregate.

and when `UserDefined` format is used, your class need to implement [IBinarySerialize Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.ibinaryserialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and override its `read` and `write` methods.

My question is what exactly these methods need to do?

Looking at the [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx), I guess they should be able to read/write the aggregation result?

For example, I am trying to create a SQL CLR function that concatenates distinct numbers. In the T-SQL I can have from 1 to 255 distinct numbers (TINYINT value). I need to create a string from them (using delimiter), but sorting the numbers as well. The function seems to work, but I am not exactly sure I have override the methods as expected:

```
[Serializable]
[
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate
    (
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.Format.UserDefined,
        IsInvariantToNulls = true,
        IsInvariantToDuplicates = true,
        IsInvariantToOrder = false,
        MaxByteSize = 1024
    )
]
public class ConcatenateAnswersPos : Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.IBinarySerialize
{
    private List<byte> intermediateResult;

    public void Init()
    {
        intermediateResult = new List<byte>();
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlByte value)
    {
        intermediateResult.Add((byte)value);
    }

    public void Merge(ConcatenateAnswersPos other)
    {
        intermediateResult.AddRange(other.intermediateResult);
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        if (intermediateResult != null)
        {
            intermediateResult.Sort();
            return new SqlString(string.Join(";", intermediateResult));
        }
        else
        {
            return new SqlString("");
        }

    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        if (r == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("r");

        intermediateResult = new List<byte>();
        string[] answers = r.ReadString().Split(';');

        foreach (string answer in answers)
        {
            intermediateResult.Add(Convert.ToByte(answer));
        }
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        if (w == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("w");
        intermediateResult.Sort();
        w.Write(string.Join(";", intermediateResult));
    }
}
```

Comment: The entirety of what you put using `Write` *must* be readable by `Read` (no more no less as in general the reader will sit on an underlying stream that does no belong only to you), but *what* exactly you put in is really opaque to the client of this interface (in general SQL Server code).

Comment: I'd take the `Sort` out of the `Write` method. Before that data is ever actually *visible* to callers, it's going to be re-processed by a call to `Read` and then (possibly after some `Merge`s) there'll be a call to `Terminate` to obtain the actual result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any particular instance of the User-Defined Aggregate (UDA) is not guaranteed to exist throughout the entire lifetime of the query. It needs to have a storable representation. When you only use value types (as noted in the "enumeration format" link in the question), the provided `Read` and `Write` methods understand how to serialize and deserialize the UDA, in which case you would use `Format.Native`. But when you start using reference types (String, collections, custom types, etc) then it is up to you to define how those values get serialized and deserialized, in which case you need to use `Format.UserDefined` and override the `Read` and `Write` methods so you can be in control of those operations.

The values that need to be serialized are anything that is needed to bring the new instance of the UDA back to the *exact* state that it was in prior to it getting serialized. This means: do not rely upon the Init() method running (it runs once per group!) or variable initializers (they run once per instantiation, and the UDA can be re-used for multiple groups without re-creating!). So you need to serialize all base values, even if they are not directly related to the final output.

---

That said, you should, at the very least, do the optimizations noted in @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer:

- Don't do the sort in the `Write` method. You are already doing it in the `Terminate` method (the appropriate place), so it is useless to do twice, not to mention very inefficient.
- Store the count of the collection and then the individual elements

Beyond that:

- When you say that your UDA "concatenates distinct numbers" if you really meant "distinct" then you need to check each number as it comes in to see if it is in the list already. I suspect this is your desire since you have `IsInvariantToDuplicates` set to true. You would do this both in the `Accumulate` method:

  ```cs
  if (!intermediateResult.Contains(value.Value))
  {
    intermediateResult.Add(value.Value);
  }
  ```

  and in the `Merge` method (called when parallelism is involved):

  ```cs
  foreach (byte _NewValue in other.intermediateResult)
  {
    if (!intermediateResult.Contains(_NewValue))
    {
      intermediateResult.Add(_NewValue);
    }
  }
  ```

  Please note that I changed your cast -- `(byte)value` -- in the `Accumulate` method into using the `Value` property. All of the `SqlTypes` (e.g. `SqlByte`, `SqlString`, `SqlInt32`, etc.) have a `Value` property that returns the .NET type that you would expect. This means that there is no need to call `ToString()` on a `SqlString` as many people seem to do.
- I would be cautious with a `MaxByteSize` of 1024. This concern would be partially mitigated by implementing @Damien's suggestions given that saving "165;207" in a string (current method) is technically 14 bytes (7 characters * 2 bytes per char) whereas saving the count and individual bytes is only 6 bytes (4 bytes for the Int32 to store the `count` + 2 individual bytes). And this disparity is just for storing 2 values. Storing 200? Yeesh!
- You do not have the [IsNullIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqluserdefinedaggregateattribute.isnullifempty.aspx) property specified. You need to specify this, especially considering that your `Terminate` method is returning an empty string if the internal collection is `null`. You should add `IsNullIfEmpty = false` since you don't want to return `NULL` if this is never called.
- The extra logic in the `Terminate` method to handle a `null` collection is probably not necessary. The collection is initialized in the `Init` and `Read` methods, so I am not sure how it could ever be `null` by the time `Terminate` is called.

---

If you want an example of creating a User-Defined Aggregate with `Format.UserDefined`, then take a look at [Getting The Most Out of SQL Server 2005 UDTs and UDAs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+CLR/3208/) (free registration required). I wrote that prior to SQL Server 2008 coming out which allowed for more than 8000 bytes to be serialized, so you can ignore (for the moment) the aspects regarding compressing the data to serialize.

Also, if you want to learn more about SQLCLR in general, I am writing a series on it for SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (same site as the first linked article).

Comment: I have already read and voted your articles and I am waiting for the rest of the series. So, using the `value` property is faster? For example, to use `value.Value` instead of `(byte)value` always. Thanks for the other tips also. Waiting for the next article :-)

Comment: @gotqn Thanks :). Not sure if using `Value` is necessarily _faster_, but definitely more consistent and reliable.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that you're doing more work in your methods than you need to. All you need to do is write enough in the `Write` method so that your `Read` method can reconstruct your internal state. Since your internal state is just a `List<byte>`, there no need to treat everything as strings:

```
public void Read(BinaryReader r)
{
    if (r == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("r");

    var count= r.ReadInt32();

    intermediateResult = new List<byte>(count);
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        intermediateResult.Add(r.ReadByte());
    }
}

public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
{
    if (w == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("w");
    w.Write(intermediateResult.Count);
    foreach(byte b in intermediateResult)
    {
      w.Write(b);
    }
}
```

And as I suggested in the comments, I've also removed the `Sort` from the `Write` method since there'll always be a final `Sort` call in `Terminate` before the data you've constructed is passed to consumers of your aggregate.

---

We store the `Count` first in the data so that we know how many times to call `ReadByte` in the `Read` method. This also allows a (probably pointless) optimization that we can tell the `List<byte>` constructor exactly how much items it needs space for.

Comment: Excellent catch/recommendation regarding how to better store the collection. I credited this answer in mine. +1

Answer (score 3):

Your aggregate can be serialized and deleted while it is half way through processing the rows it operates on. The database engine can then create a new instance and deserialize to get back to where it left off.

As such the `Write` method needs to be able to store the state of the aggregate when only some of the records have been passed to `Accumulate`. The `Read` method needs to be able to set the aggregate back up ready for more calls on `Accumulate` or `Merge`.

As such I would say that you have implemented these correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The [`IBianarySerialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.ibinaryserialize.aspx) methods are for saving your object and restoring it in case it needs to be written to disk.

As such, the [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.ibinaryserialize.write.aspx) method should save everything needed to recreate the object in its current state (the data) and the [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.ibinaryserialize.read.aspx) method should take what was output by Write and set the object's state (so it matches the original).

The other answers seem pretty good at addressing the issues with this process, though I do recommend keeping the data you are reading/writing using these methods as small and fast as possible.